# SVN refuses to commit. No updates required

Tags: eclipse, svn, zend-studio

I am using Flash Builder for PHP 4.5 to work on a php project. It is essentially Zend Studio which is built on top of eclipse.

I've moved some folders and files, renamed some files from within Flash Builder. Some files were also removed. I then attempted to commit to SVN.

SVN comes back with an error saying commit failed as one of the files is not up to date. Conincidentally, this is also one of the files that was removed.

I then proceeded to do an update first and got the message: No changes to merge.

Trying to commit again just results in an error saying that the files are not up to date.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: When you did the update, did you revert everything in your working copy first, or did you try to update on your dirty working copy (including deleted file)?  SVN is very fickle about working copies...

Comment: Delete was done in Flash builder, so I am assuming it has made all the required changes to the working copy. No revert was done. I did try to update the working copy (dirty) after the commit failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it's the deleted file that's making your commits fail, you can try reverting the deleted file, then updating, then deleting again, but if that fails, you might want to consider making a copy of the changes you made in your WC, revert the originals, update the originals, then copy all the changes back.

OR, if you're sure that it's only that deleted file that's making the commit fail, then commit everything else first, then go back and revert the deleted file, update, then delete and commit again. Like I said, SVN is fickle about dirty working copies...

Comment: In the end, I just checked out a temp copy, copied the changes over from the dirty WC and then checked back in. Thanks for your help :)